# How can I give a constant value to a variable in julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I have a 2 dimensional matrix variable which it should get a constant value. for example

```
@variable(model1,x[h=1:3,6]==I[h=1:3,6])
```

I: is a constant matrix. but in code it gives this error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching constructvariable!(::JuMP.Model, ::JuMP.#_error#103{Tuple{Sym
bol,Expr}}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Symbol, ::String, ::Float64)
```

would you please help me? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to asign `h` again, just use it as index:

```
@variable(model1, x[h=1:3,6] == I[h,6])
```